# PDFMiner Acroforms Acrobat PDFMaker not able to extract text

Tags: python, pdfminer

I am using the below code to try and extract text out of a PDF form that was first made in MS Word and then converted to a form in Acrobat Pro. In doc properties it says **Acrobat PDFMaker 22**.

```py
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1
from pdfminer.psparser import PSLiteral, PSKeyword
from pdfminer.utils import decode_text

file_path = r'myPDF.pdf'
data = {}


def decode_value(value):
    # decode PSLiteral, PSKeyword
    if isinstance(value, (PSLiteral, PSKeyword)):
        value = value.name

    # decode bytes
    if isinstance(value, bytes):
        value = decode_text(value)

    return value


with open(file_path, 'rb') as fp:
    parser = PDFParser(fp)

    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    res = resolve1(doc.catalog)

    if 'AcroForm' not in res:
        raise ValueError("No AcroForm Found")

    fields = resolve1(doc.catalog['AcroForm'])['Fields']  # may need further resolving
    
    p = Path(file_path)
    print(f'Form name# {p.stem}')

    for f in fields:
        # extract normal text
        # text = extract_text(file_path)
        # print(text)

        field = resolve1(f)
        name, values = field.get('T'), field.get('V')

        # decode name
        name = decode_text(name)

        # resolve indirect obj
        values = resolve1(values)

        # decode value(s)
        if isinstance(values, list):
            values = [decode_value(v) for v in values]
        else:
            values = decode_value(values)

        data.update({name: values})

        print(name, values)
```

I am not able to extract the text and get this error.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\GOLDSB~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20804/1611217105.py in <module>
     24 
     25     if 'AcroForm' not in res:
---> 26         raise ValueError("No AcroForm Found")
     27 
     28     fields = resolve1(doc.catalog['AcroForm'])['Fields']  # may need further resolving

ValueError: No AcroForm Found
```

Here is some details about PDFMaker
https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/creating-pdfs-pdfmaker-windows.html

I should add that this code works fine when using forms made only in Acrobat Pro, in doc properties it says  **Adobe Acrobat Pro DC**

Is there anyway to get this to work? I would like to stick with starting the forms in word and turning them into forms in Acrobat Pro. But I need to be able to extract the text to a database.

-- Edit --

Here is what my test form looks like and it goes through three steps:-

1. produce text in MS Word
2. convert to PDF in MS Word
3. prepare form in Acrobat Pro

[image]

Comment: @KJ 1) but the fields are not being made in MS Word. The PDF is made in Word and the fields are made in Acrobat Pro. 4) I am testing with the most basic word file with just two fields.

Answer (score 0):

So I have cracked it. Go through this process but after step 3, add a new field while in Acrobat Pro. It will prompt to **save as**. This new saved form will be an Acroform and PDFMiner will be able to extract the text.

Output

```
Form name# basic form as form
Field 1 this is text 1
Field 2 this is text 2
Text1 this is text 3
```